# Extract a substring from a string

Tags: c#, substring

How can I extract substring "Amy Java" from below string in C#?

```
CN=Amy Java,OU=Singapore,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?, then add in the question.

Comment: From the looks of it; it seems to be a LDAP string. In that case, you can definitely get domain name.

Comment: I am getting the above string in a textbox and from that I need to extract the substring "Amy Java"

Comment: split it by ',', then split the output by '='

Comment: I already marked an answer but the author deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var amyJavaText =
    "CN=Amy Java,OU=Singapore,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Split('='))
        .ToLookup(x => x[0], x => x[1])["CN"]
        .First();
```

Comment: it's a bit of overkill but i like that you looked for the key

Comment: I hope the name doesn't have any escaped/quoted `,` or `=` characters in...

Comment: @Rawling - Yes, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

it's all you need.

```
string result = str.Split(',')[0].Split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to more generic way, you can create a `Dictionary` (in case of unique values in String provided) or List of `KeyValuePair` (for current string example) as follow:

```
var str = "CN=Amy Java,OU=Singapore,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";

var dict = str.Split(',').Select(s=> s.Split('=')).ToDictionary(a => a[0].Trim(), a => a[1].Trim()); //Only if Key are unique 
var kvp =  str.Split(',').Select(s=> s.Split('=')).Select(a=> new KeyValuePair<string,string>( a[0].Trim(), a[1].Trim()));
```

Then you can use another `Linq` to select the key required.

```
var requiredValue = kvp.Where(u=> u.Key == "CN").Value;
```

will give you required value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string[] FindKeyValue(string str, string key)
{
    return str.Split(",".ToCharArray())
        .Select(x => x.Split("=".ToCharArray()))
        .Where(x => x[0] == key).Select(x => x[1]).ToArray();
}
```

Assuming you want know the value of CN, OU, DC etc. The string you have, looks like a key value pair where "CN" is a key and "Amy Java" is a value. It seems that a key can be present multiple times in the string. Therefore you have more than one value for a key.
Use it as follows:

```
var str1 = "CN=Amy Java,OU=Singapore,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";
string[] valuesOfCN = FindKeyValue(str1, "CN");
```

If you want just a single value such as first value then use

```
var str1 = "CN=Amy Java,OU=Singapore,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com";
string firstValueOfCN = FindKeyValue(str1, "CN").First();
```